# Deforming a non-positively curved Riemannian manifold into a negatively curved one

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

*Cheeger deformations* can be used to deform some non-negatively curved Riemannian manifolds into positively curved manifolds (e.g., sectional curvatures strictly positve), see 
[What is a Cheeger deformation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49002/what-is-a-cheeger-deformation).

I would like to ask: **Is there a similar, or at least somehow comparable  method of deforming a non-positively curved Riemannian manifold into a negatively curved one?**

In particular, I would be very interested in such a method for compact Riemannian locally symmetric spaces of Rank $>1$, which are non-positively curved but not negatively curved.